# SSRS - Is it possible to have a value axis that displays text based on a function instead of numbers

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012

When creating a Chart, is it possible to have a value axis (not category axis) that displays labels based on a function instead of the actual numbers? eg. assuming a minimum of 0, a maximum of 7, and an interval of 1, instead of showing 0 to 7 on the axis it would show N, G, F, E, D, C, B, A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [StripLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239316(v=sql.110).aspx). This was only useful for me because the range of my y-axis was fixed. To add them to the y-axis:

1. click on the y-axis.
2. in the Properties under Appearance, click the elipsis for "StripLines".
3. you can then add a strip line for each y-label you require. I modified only the Title, TitleFont, IntervalOffset, and TitleVerticalAlign (middle) for each strip line.